# ind-completion and functors which are full with respect to isomorphisms

Tags: category-theory, model-theory

Let $C$ and $D$ be categories and $F:C\rightarrow D$ a faithful functor which is full with respect to isomorphisms. This means that if $a,b\in C$ and $f:F(a)\rightarrow F(b)$ is an isomorphism in $D$, then $f$ is in the image of the functor $F$.

Suppose further that $D$ has all filtered colimits over diagrams in the image of $F$, so that $F$ induces a functor $\hat{F}:\text{ind-}C\rightarrow D$. Here  [$\text{ind-}C$](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ind-object) is the free ind-completion of $C$ obtained by formally adjoining all filtered colimits.

**Question:** Under what circumstances is $\hat{F}$ full with respect to isomorphisms?

**Edit:** Since posing the question, I've learned some more terminology from the nLab, and I can add some more restrictions. I am actually interested in the case when the image of $F$ in $D$ is closed under isomorphism, i.e. $F$ is an [isofibration](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/isofibration), equivalently $F(C)$ is a [replete subcategory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/replete+subcategory) of $D$. Perhaps more usefully, we may assume that every object in $F(C)$ is a [compact object](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/compact+object) in $D$. Finally, if it's relevant, we may assume that every arrow in $D$ is monic.

---

Motivation (from model theory): In generalized Fraïssé theory (a.k.a. Hrushovski constructions), one often works with a distinguished "strong substructure" relation $\preceq$ between finite $L$-structures in a specified class $K$. Some basic assumptions are that our class $K$ and the relation $\preceq$ are closed under isomorphism, and that $\preceq$ is reflexive and transitive. Then we have a notion of strong embedding ($f:A\rightarrow B$ is strong iff $f(A) \preceq B$), and the category $C_K$ whose objects are $K$ and whose arrows are the strong embeddings is a replete subcategory of the category $C_L$ of all $L$-structures and embeddings.

Now we are not just interested in the structures in $K$, but also the infinite structures which are built from them (the Fraïssé limit in particular), and we want to talk about when a finite structure $A$ in $K$ is a strong substructure of a structure $M$, which is a direct limit along a diagram of strong embeddings.

Clearly any structure appearing in the direct limit diagram should be a strong substructure of $M$, as should any strong substructure of such a structure, by transitivity. So we could take the strong embeddings into $M$ to be those which factor as a strong embedding into one of the structures in the diagram, followed by the inclusion into the direct limit. These are exactly the maps which appear in the construction of $\text{ind-}C_K$, so they're the ones which are in the image of $\hat{F}$ above.

But it's possible that the resulting notion is not isomorphism invariant. That is, there could be another direct limit $M'$ and an isomorphism (in $C_L$) $\sigma:M\rightarrow M'$ and a finite structure $A\preceq M$ such that $\sigma(A) \npreceq M'$.

A map from the formal colimit of a directed system $(A_i)$ to the formal limit of a directed system $(B_i)$ in $\text{ind-}C_K$ is a choice for each $A_i$ of a strong embedding into some $B_j$ such that all resulting diagrams commute. So given $\sigma:M\cong M'$ where $M$ and $M'$ are direct limits, $M = \text{colim}(A_i)$, $M' = \text{colim}(B_i)$, along strong embeddings, $\sigma$ is in the image of $\hat{F}$ if and only if each $A_i$ embeds strongly in some $B_j$ by a restriction of $\sigma$ and each $B_i$ embeds strongly in some $A_j$ by a restriction of $\sigma^{-1}$. This happens if and only if whenever $A\preceq M$, $\sigma(A) \preceq M'$. So the resulting strong substructure notion is isomorphism-invariant if and only if $\hat{F}$ is full with respect to isomorphisms.

Another way of putting it is that whenever we have two presentations of a structure $M$ as direct limits along strong embeddings, these two presentations "fit together".

What I'm looking for is a weak condition, or better a characterization, in terms of properties of the $\preceq$ relation, of when this happens. For example, it certainly happens if $A \preceq C$ and $A \subseteq B \subseteq C$ implies $A \preceq B$, which is often the case in interesting examples (for example, whenever $A \preceq -$ is definable by a universal theory with parameters from $A$).

Comment: Q1. This is sometimes called "full with respect to isomorphisms". See Definition 4.9 [here](http://www.math.muni.cz/~rosicky/papers/elem7.pdf).

Comment: That's a very natural name, and that's a very interesting paper you've linked me to. Thanks!

Comment: I thought you might like it. There's a related [presentation](http://www.math.muni.cz/~rosicky/papers/cam2.pdf) where Rosický calls the property "iso-full" instead.

Comment: I'm not sure I see the connection between what you're asking and what you want to do. My interpretation is that you are looking for a condition that says that there are no more $L$-isomorphisms between direct limits of $K$-structures than what you would get by taking _formal_ direct limits.

Comment: That's right. Let's say I have some infinite structure $M$ and a presentation of $M$ as a direct limit along $K$-structures and strong embeddings. Then a $K$-substructure of $M$ should be strong just when the inclusion factors through one of the embeddings in the direct limit. But this isn't necessarily isomorphism invariant. That's fine, I can say that $A$ is a strong substructure just when there *exists* some presentation of $M$ as a direct limit with the above property. What I'd like is a condition for when this extra step isn't necessary.

Comment: What you just said seems to be something different again. If all $K$-structures are compact ("finitely presentable", to algebraically inclined folks) as $L$-structures, then a $K$-substructure of a direct limit of $K$-structures _must_ factor through one of the objects appearing in the direct system (but the inclusion is possibly _not_ strong). This is already isomorphism-invariant.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "just when the inclusion factors *strongly* through one of the embeddings in the direct limit".

Comment: Hmmm. That happens if and only if the inclusion of the $K$-substructure is isomorphic to something in the image of $\hat{F}$. If you want to eliminate the isomorphism then you want $\hat{F}$ to be an isofibration, which can be done by replacing $\mathbf{Ind}(\mathcal{C})$ with an equivalent (but in general different) category. Still, I don't see where iso-fullness comes into the story.

Comment: Okay, I'll edit the question soon with more details about how (I believe) the question is the same as the motivation. I just phrased things in the categorical language in hopes that the answer might be obvious to a category theorist (you).

Comment: I still don't agree with your conclusion that iso-fullness is relevant to the problem. Firstly, an $L$-structure may be isomorphic to an object in the image of $\hat{F}$ without literally being in the image of $\hat{F}$ – so iso-fullness won't ensure isomorphism-invariance. Secondly, once you replace "morphism in the image of $\hat{F}$" with "isomorphic to a morphism in the image of $\hat{F}$", you automatically get all isomorphisms, so you don't need iso-fullness either. Thirdly, if you don't build in isomorphism-invariance into the definition, then you get sensitive dependence on $\hat{F}$,

Comment: (cont.) which is (typically) only defined up to isomorphism in terms of $F$.

Comment: "My interpretation is that you are looking for a condition that says that there are no more L-isomorphisms between direct limits of K-structures than what you would get by taking formal direct limits.". Is this not the question of whether the canonical map from ind-$C_K$ into $C_L$ is iso-full?